# kill() function is not recognized for child_process

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process, kill-process

Using node js I'm calling external script in MATLAB and Python
That is working well using terminal commands to run the scripts using those application ('start')

But when I'm trying to close them using kill() ('stop') I get an error:

> TypeError: exec.kill is not a function

I'm using MAC OS and this is my code:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

const exec = require('child_process').exec;
var cmd1 =
  '/Applications/MATLAB_R2016b.app/bin/matlab -nojvm  < /Users/dorsimon/Desktop/liftrack/Testing_Classifier.m';
var cmd2 = 'python /Users/dorsimon/Desktop/liftrack/arduino_sampling_for_workout.py';

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendfile('index.html');
});

//Whenever someone connects this gets executed
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.log('A user connected');

  fs.watch('/Users/dorsimon/Desktop/liftrack/result/', function(event, test) {
    console.log('event is: ' + event);
    fs.readFile('/Users/dorsimon/Desktop/liftrack/result/results.csv', 'utf-8', function read(
      err,
      data
    ) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('err');
        throw err;
      }
      console.log(data);
      socket.send(data);
    });
  });

  fs.watch('/Users/dorsimon/Desktop/liftrack/go', function(event, test) {
    console.log('event is: ' + event);
    fs.readFile('/Users/dorsimon/Desktop/liftrack/go/go.csv', 'utf-8', function read(err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('err');
        throw err;
      }
      console.log(data);
      socket.send(data);
    });
  });

  //Whenever someone disconnects this piece of code executed
  socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    console.log('A user disconnected');
  });

  socket.on('start', function() {
    exec(cmd1, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
      // command output is in stdout
    });
    exec(cmd2, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
      // command output is in stdout
    });
  });

  socket.on('stop', function() {
    exec.kill();
  });
});

http.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

How can I kill those child_process that I started?

Thanks
Dor

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the return value of `exec` and call `kill` on that. You can store those values as properties on `socket` for convenience:

```
socket.on('start', function() {
  socket.child1 = exec(cmd1, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    // command output is in stdout
  });
  socket.child2 = exec(cmd2, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    // command output is in stdout
  });
});

socket.on('stop', function() {
  socket.child1.kill();
  socket.child2.kill();
});
```

FWIW, you probably have to do the same with the return values of `fs.watch()`, and call [`close()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_watcher_close) on them when the socket gets closed, otherwise you'll probably run into issues after your server has been running for a while (it creates two watchers for each `socket.io` connection, but doesn't remove them, so they'll linger).